# Change Blur Distance in SCNKit scene

Tags: swift, render, scenekit

The blur distance in my scene only blurs out the SCNFloor node at a distance. I am trying to get the blur removed from the scene. All the other nodes are not affected. This is what the scene renders...

[image: The road blurs while no other node in the scene blurs.]

Ive tired using Apple's documents to fix the focus distance of the camera, but it seems that that does not work.

```
        cameraNode.camera?.focusDistance = 100
        cameraNode.camera?.fStop = 100
        cameraNode.camera?.apertureBladeCount = 100
        cameraNode.camera?.focalBlurSampleCount = 100
        cameraNode.camera?.motionBlurIntensity = 0
```

Ive also tried to change the focus distance in the render functions of the scene. This also failed.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        //Other code to deal with the follow camera
        cameraNode.camera?.focusDistance = 100
    }
```

Would the solution be something to do with the floor node or the camera node?

Comment: `fStop` 100 is probably not right.  For shallow depth of field, you want a small number.  Maybe try something like 1.4 or 2.0 or 2.8.  (I'd leave the blade count at something more moderate like 6 to 10 as well.  100 is going to be way overkill for getting circular-looking blur.)  And be sure to enable `wantsDepthOfField`, otherwise the effects are disabled. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/2881741-wantsdepthoffield

Comment: @bg2b I tried your suggestions. Im trying to omit the blur. After attempting your suggestions, the blur  did not go away or travel farther down the road.

Comment: Please edit the question. The beginning sentences seem to be asking why only the ground was affected, with the implication that you wanted blur throughout the scene.  So the real question is why are you getting blur on the ground, and how can you get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrighty, so after some deep research I was able to find a solution. Turns out the Anisotropy of the floor node was not set to the desired value. So here is the solution,

The solution had nothing to do with the camera. Wherever you set up your scene, add this line:

```
  yourSceneName.rootNode.childNode(withName: "yourFloorNodeName", recursively: true)?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.maxAnisotropy = 50 //Change according to preference.
```

This solves the entire problem.